# Logic in models based on object information

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Is there a way to embed logic in to Django's model layer, using logic from other fields of the object? This sounds complicated, so I wrote some example code. I don't want to use inheritance, all of my fields but one are shared and it would overcomplicate things.

```
class Creature(models.Model):
    numberOfEyes = models.IntegerField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

This is just what I am trying to accomplish, not meant to work

```
if self.numberOfEyes == 1:
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
     ('cyclops', 'cyclops')
)
else:
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
    # You get the idea
)
```

Is there a way to embed this logic at the model layer? Or do I have to define this in the form?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use inheritance if the field really is shared between different models.

However, it looks like you want the choices to be different for different models, so inheritance wouldn't work in this case.

Here are some options:

1. Just have a different `type` field for each of your models. If you only have a few models this is the way to go because it's simple.
2. Muck with undocumented Django internals. i.e. set `_choices` in `__init__()` I wouldn't recommend this because if Django changes this variable or how the variable is used, your code will break. Anyways, here's some pseudo-code for this:

   ```
   class Creature(models.Model):

       numberOfEyes = models.IntegerField()
       type = models.CharField(max_length=30)

       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
             super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
             for f in self._meta.fields:
                 if f.name == "type":
                     f._choices = ('choice1', 'choice2')
   ```
3. Use metaclasses to construct the models. Metaclasses are classes used to create classes. I won't even try to come up with the Metaclass pseudo-code for this because it will probably not work. Django has it's own Metaclass and Metaclass inheritance is complicated. But the idea would be to create the type field in your custom Metaclass with a class level variable specifying what choices to use for the type field. Here's pseudo-code for the usage of the custom Metaclass:

   ```
   class Creature(models.Model):
       __metaclass__ = MyMetaClass

       TYPE_CHOICES = ('choice1', 'choice2')

       numberOfEyes = models.IntegerField()
       type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   ```